# SignalR (serverless) .NET console client not receiving messages

Tags: azure, azure-functions, signalr, signalr.client

I'm trying to learn SignalR by creating a sample .NET console application that receive messages through a serverless SignalR, via a hosted Azure function app; I've been following this tutorial https://www.nikouusitalo.com/blog/qr-code-pings-with-azure-functions-and-azure-signalr/ but even though I get the connection stablished, I never get any message when running a POST request against a given Azure function in Postman. This is what I have:

Azure Functions

```
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalR(HubName = "QRCodeRehash")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            await signalRMessages.AddAsync(
                new SignalRMessage
                {
                    Target = "pingQR",
                    Arguments = new[] { "ping" }
                });

            var responseMessage = "Success";

            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
        }

        [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public static SignalRConnectionInfo GetOrderNotificationsSignalRInfo(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")] HttpRequest req,
            [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "QRCodeRehash")] SignalRConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
        {
            return connectionInfo;
        }
    }
```

.NET Console application to receive message

```
        public class SignalRConnection
        {
            public async void Start()
            {
                var url = "https://sample.azurewebsites.net/api";

                var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .WithUrl(url)
                    .WithAutomaticReconnect()
                    .Build();

                // receive a message from the hub
                connection.On<string, string>("pingQR", (user, message) => OnReceiveMessage(user, message));

                await connection.StartAsync();
            }

            private void OnReceiveMessage(string user, string message)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{user}: {message}");
            }

        }
```

And following the tutorial's steps, I just call Function1 in Postman:

[image: Postman]

I always get "200 OK" and the logs can be seen in the Azure function as well; also, the negotiate works ok as it seems to connect every time to SignalR:

[image: Azure logstream]

I've set CORS in the Azure function app to allow anything while I get this to work:

[image: Azure function CORS]

I would appreciate your help on this; it's odd how it works for the tutorial's owner, however, maybe something was left out that I need to do on my end, so any thoughts would be highly appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

**Update:** Thanks @Brennan's comment, my mistake was in to providing a different number of arguments than the ones detailed in the connection in the client. It's working as expected now.

Comment: I think the issue is that you're expecting two arguments on the .NET Console app side `(user, message)` but only sending one from the function `Arguments = new[] { "ping" }`

Comment: Thanks @Brennan, that did the trick! as soon as I matched the arguments with what I was expecting, it worked! it's kind of odd that there are no errors, anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a Debug log on the client side